# If statement to change variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's an excerpt from my script. (The variables Q, N, Z and, X are in a different part of the script, don't worry about that.)

```
e1 = 4
e2 = 5
p1 = 4
p2 = 5
def firstPoint():
    if Q == 1:
       print(p2 - N)
    if Q == 2:
        print(p2 + N)
    if Q == 3:
        print(p1 + N)
    if Q == 4:
        print(p1 - N)
def secondPoint():
    if Z == 1:
       print(e2 - X)
    if Z == 2:
        print(e2 + X)
    if Z == 3:
        print(e1 + X)
    if Z == 4:
        print(e1 - X)
firstPoint()
secondPoint()
```

If one of the statements is true then maybe save it or edit it to a variable in the function that I could make global.

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how I would do this so that I can use the information in a later function without having a million variables as I already have a lot to keep track of.

Edit:
I need to plug in e1, e2, p1, p2 into a distance formula if that helps clarify.

Comment: It's not super-clear what you are asking, but typically if you want to use a value that was create in a function, you would return that value. You would not use global variables.

Comment: why dont you send a list that has all these values instead of creating variables. A list can contain all these values. And use return so it can send the values back

Comment: An example would be `def firstPoint(my_vars):` do the checks and store to local variable. Then update my_vars with the final result, then `return my_vars`. That way you get the values as well for use

Comment: See if this website helps you understand how to do it. https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/fopp/Functions/Returningavaluefromafunction.html

Comment: Given the statement that there are millions of variables, etc., and that `e1`, `e2`, `p1` and `p2` would differ, I would consider reading up about object-oriented programming. You could make it easier to build an object model that has `firstPoint()` and `secondPoint()`

Answer (score 0):

6 variables in this short snippet of code is way too many. We can simplify things a bit [by using functions](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions).

`firstPoint` and `secondPoint` basically do the same thing, so we can make a function that does that instead. I'm going to call it `get_point` (snake case is preferred in Python). It's going to have 3 parameters:

- `query` - what you have as `Q` and `Z`.
- `a` and `b` - you should give these a better name, but I don't know what they're for. I'm using them instead of `e1`, `e2`, `p1`, `p2`.
- `constant` - the number you add or subtract (`N` or `Z`).

Instead of printing out whichever if statement passed, I'm going to make the function return that.

```py
def get_point(query, constant, a, b):
    # there's probably better logic for this, but I have no context
    if query == 1:
        return b - constant
    elif query == 2:
        return b + constant
    elif query == 3:
        return a + constant
    elif query == 4:
        return a - constant
    return None  # if query isn't 1, 2, 3, or 4
```

Now we can simplify your code into:

```
first_point = get_point(Q, N, 4, 5)  # query=Q, constant=N, a=e1=4, b=e2=5
second_point = get_point(Z, X, 4, 5)  # query=Z, constant=Z, a=p1=4, b=[2=5

# the previous outputs are saved into variables, 
# but we can still print them if needed

print("1st point:", first_point)
print("2nd point:", second_point)
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks alot! since the variables are just a single float id have too get the other x or y of the point depending if i was adding or subtracting the constant. sorry I dont really know much I just strated learning python. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction! (edit i need the points in x, y format for the distance formula.)